# Repeat data on each page while printing in html

Tags: html, css

I have two tables say Table A and Table B. The Table A is the first table and it will be printed on each page then the table B will be printed. The Table B has huge no. of datas. So while printing the Table B the header of Table B will be printed on each page.

E.g.

| Table A Header1 | Table A Header 2 | Table A Header 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Content A1 | Content A2 | Content A3 |
| Content A4 | Content A5 | Content A6 |

This is Table A and it will be printed on each page.

| Table B Header1 | Table B Header 2 | Table B Header 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Content B1 | Content B2 | Content B3 |
| Content B4 | Content B5 | Content B6 |

This is Table B and there is huge content for Table B. So the header part of Table B will be printed on each page along with table A and below the Table A.

This I want to achieve in HTML and CSS.

I have tried using CSS like the below

```
header {
  display: table-header-group;
}

section {
  display: table-row-group;
}

footer {
  display: table-footer-group;
}
```

but though it prints as i desired but the second table overlaps the 1st table on the 2nd page onwards.

Comment: i tried to create a table say "Table-1". In the thead part of the "Table 1" i put "Table A" and in the tbody part iput "Table B". While printing the Table A is repeated in each page, but the header part of Table B is not repeated. Can any body help me to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved this by following method.

1. I created a table.
2. In the header part ()section I created the Table A. The trick is i put the entire content of Table A, in  then  then inside  tag.
3. Then in the body part  i created the Table B using  then then  tag.
4. Now it is working, but when i use scale value while printing it is overlaping.